# How to select the div tag with the value of text node of label tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

```
<abc>
  <div>
    <input>
    <label>A
      <span>C</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input>
    <label>AB
      <span>D</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</abc>
```

I need to select the `<div>` tag with search criteria of text in the `<label>` tag. Text inside `<span>` is dynamic and sometimes it is empty, so this should not be used as search criteria.

What I have so far tried is below, both could not return the answer:

```
//div[./label[.='A']]

//div[./label[text().='A']]
```

Comment: Try this xpath: `//div[./label[contains(.,'A')]]`

Comment: I cant use 'contains', since node value of other label tag is 'AB', so it will select both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it with `ancestor` (first will select `div` with label "A", second will select `div` with label "AB") :

```
//label[./text()[normalize-space()="A"]]/ancestor::div
//label[./text()[normalize-space()="AB"]]/ancestor::div
```

With `contains` function :

```
//label[contains(./text(),"A") and string-length(normalize-space(./text()))=1]/ancestor::div
//label[contains(./text(),"AB")]/ancestor::div
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent`:

```
//label[text()='A']//parent::div
```

Also you can use text contains:

```
//label[contains(text(),'A')]//parent::div
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the parent `<div>` element with respect to it's child `<label>` element's text using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Selecting `<div>` with child `<label>` text as **AB**

  ```
  //div[//label[contains(., 'AB')]]
  ```

> **Note**: [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) still doesn't supports [xpath-2.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-2.0) so you have to use [xpath-1.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0)